# How to update the changes to my react native app built with expo?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, apk

I am new to react native. Recently I built a simple react native app with expo. I also generated an apk file of it. Now I have made some changes to the codes and now how can I update this changes to my app and also the users who has installed the app on their phones? (My app is not published to play store.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in [expo-updates](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/updates/) library